# Query fails to load data in the way I expect, overwrites existing data

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `user_pen_names` (`uid`,`pnid`,`my_name`) VALUES ('7','200','stink') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `my_name`=values(`my_name`)
```

My table has the following columns defined:

```
id   INT  primary, auto-increment
uid  INT  unsigned, unique
pnid INT  unsigned, unique
my_name VARCHAR(24)
```

I have one table entry already:

```
id(0), uid(7), pnid(100), my_name(test)
```

When I execute the above query, what I expected to see was two rows:

```
id(0), uid(7), pnid(100), my_name(test)
id(1), uid(7), pnid(200), my_name(stink)
```

What's happening, and I am one confused puppy because of it, is that the existing row is being modified...

```
id(0), uid(7), pnid(100), my_name(stink)
```

The same thing happens if I modify uid and pnid so they are no longer unique.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

**EDIT** I made the two columns combinationally unique using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_pen_names` ADD UNIQUE KEY `upn_unique_id` (`uid`, `pnid`)
```

I've not done this before, but theoretically, the INSERT command should only shift to its UPDATE sub-command when uid AND pnid match a row already in the table.  Nevertheless, this also didn't work.

Comment: Why are you inserting numbers as strings?

Comment: Habit, though it's not caused me trouble before.  I removed the quotes and get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. I suspect you didn't run the test you thought you were running.

I tested on a Macbook with MySQL 8.0.1:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `user_pen_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pnid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `my_name` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`,`pnid`)
);

mysql> INSERT INTO `user_pen_names` (id, `uid`,`pnid`,`my_name`) VALUES (0, '7','100','test');

mysql> INSERT INTO `user_pen_names` (`uid`,`pnid`,`my_name`) VALUES ('7','200','stink') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `my_name`=values(`my_name`);

mysql> SELECT * FROM user_pen_names;
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | uid  | pnid | my_name |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 |    7 |  100 | test    |
|  2 |    7 |  200 | stink   |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

Note that when you insert a 0 into an auto-increment column, it generates a new id, starting at 1.

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  I had to delete my table and use the CREATE pattern you suggested.  I must have had some gremlin I'd created duing my efforts to figure this out.  Cheers, mate!

Answer (score 0):

You have uid & pnid set as unique. So because you can't insert another uid=7, it's modifying the 7 row that has uid of 7 already.

Comment: I see your point, although as I mentioned, if I make them "un-unique", I get the same result.  Note that it's the combination of uid and pnid that I'd like to be unique.  Is it possible to set the table that way?